# Array divide/split by value

Tags: php, arrays, function

```
$a = array(8, 16, 16, 32, 8, 8, 4, 4);
```

With an array like the one above is there a way so I can divide/split the array based on the value suming up to a set value.  e.g  if I wanted them to equal 32.  My final array will have upto 100 values all being either 32, 16, 8 or 4 and I just need to group the items so the value always equal a set amount so in this example  its 32.

From the above array I would would hope to get:

```
$a[0][1] = 16
$a[0][2] = 16

$a[1][3] = 32

$a[2][0] = 8
$a[2][4] = 8
$a[2][5] = 8
$a[2][6] = 4
$a[2][7] = 4
```

as $a[0] sums up to 32 and so does $a[1] and $a[2].

Comment: why would you get `[[16,16],[32],[8,8,8,4,4]]` and not, as an example,  `[[32], [8,8,16], [4,4,8,16]]`? Or does it not matter?

Comment: ow it doesnt matter what the groups are made up of as long as they sum to 32  sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Seconded - does it matter how they're combined as long as it totals 32? Also what to do if the total isn't a multiple of 32?

Comment: looks similar to a magic square: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square

Comment: if there is an excess that doesnt multiply it would be nice hjust to see it in a seperate element at the end.  But yes your completely rigth it doesnt matter which of the items its groups as long as they sum to 32.  Ideally the more random the groupings was the bettrer as the values are sizes of adverts in a newspaper.

Comment: So all groups except the last one need to be exactly 32 (some modification of the knapsack problem)?

Comment: @FF: The point about "ideally the more random the groupings the better" makes the question quite different as the most efficient algorithms for this would all start by sorting the array and talking out the larger elements first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$a = array(8, 16, 16, 32, 8, 8, 4, 4);
$limit = 32;
rsort($a);
$b = array(array());
$index = 0;
foreach($a as $i){
    if($i+array_sum($b[$index]) > $limit){
        $b[++$index] = array();
    }
    $b[$index][] = $i;
}
$a = $b;
print_r($a);
```

It will work, but only because in your case you have 4 | 8 | 16 | 32, and only if the needed sum is a multiple of the biggest number (32).

Test: http://codepad.org/5j5nl3dT

Note: `|` means `divides`.

Comment: `|` is a bitwise operator meaning `OR`, why did  you just not do `4 / 8 / 16 / 32` ?

Comment: @Robert I was referring to the `|` used in Math. Sorry if it created confusion. By using that chaining I tried to point out that each number divides the next one. `4 / 8 / 16 / 32` just equals `O` it doesn't tell you anything more.

Comment: No problems, a lot of members get confused with Bitwise Operators including myself at times, just making sure that there's no confusion, great block of code aswell :) +1

Answer (score 0):

```
function split_into_thirtytwos($input_array) {
  $output_array=array();
  $work_array=array();
  $sum=0;
  sort($input_array,SORT_NUMERIC);
  while(count($input_array)>0) {
    $sum=array_sum($work_array)+$input_array[count($input_array)-1];
    if($sum<=32) {
        $work_array[]=array_pop($input_array);
    } else {
      $output_array[]=$work_array;
      $work_array=array();
    }
  }
  if(count($work_array)>0) {$output_array[]=$work_array;}
  return $output_array;
}
```

Tested with your input:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 32
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16
        [1] => 16
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 8
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 4
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array(8, 16, 16, 32, 8, 8, 4, 4);
$group_limit = 32;


$current_group = $result = array();
$cycles_since_successful_operation = 0;

while ($a && $cycles_since_successful_operation < count($a))
{
    array_push($current_group,array_shift($a));

    if (array_sum($current_group) > $group_limit)
        array_push($a,array_pop($current_group));
    elseif (array_sum($current_group) < $group_limit)
        $cycles_since_successful_operation = 0;
    elseif (array_sum($current_group) == $group_limit)
    {
        $result []= $current_group;
        $current_group = array();
        $cycles_since_successful_operation = 0;
    }
}
if ($a)
    $result []= $a; // Remaining elements form the last group
```

http://codepad.org/59wmsi4g